# In Python, How do I check whether a file exists starting or ending with a substring?

Tags: python, file, filesystems, substring

I know about `os.path.isfile(fname)`, but now I need to search if a file exists that is named `FILEnTEST.txt` where n could be any positive integer (so it could be `FILE1TEST.txt` or `FILE9876TEST.txt`)

I guess a solution to this could involve substrings that the filename starts/ends with OR one that involves somehow calling `os.path.isfile('FILE' + n + 'TEST.txt')` and replacing n with any number, but I don't know how to approach either solution.

Answer (score 12):

You would need to write your own filtering system, by getting all the files in a directory and then matching them to a regex string and seeing if they fail the test or not:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("FILE\d+TEST.txt")
dir = "/test/"
for filepath in os.listdir(dir):
    if pattern.match(filepath):
        #do stuff with matching file
```

I'm not near a machine with Python installed on it to test the code, but it should be something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
/FILE\d+TEST.txt/
```

Example: [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3g4ur).

Then you can use said regular expression and iterate through all of the files in a directory.

```
import re
import os

filename_re = 'FILE\d+TEST.txt'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if re.search(filename_re, filename):
        # this file has the form FILEnTEST.txt
        # do what you want with it now
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it as such:

```
import os
import re

if len([file for file in os.listdir(directory) if re.search('regex', file)]):
    # there's at least 1 such file
```